# How disable div element on iframe by sandbox?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

How disable div element on iframe by sandbox? I searched in internet about this subject but I didn't find anything about it , Please guide me how is it possible ?

in the source code of this iframe :

```
<div id="countDown"
                        style="display: ; font-family:verdana; font-size:10px;
                               text-align:center;color:#ffffff;position:absolute;top:182.5px;
                               left:360px; z-index:10000000">Close the ads in 
                               <span id="count">30 </span> seconds
                    </div>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:hideOverlay('total')" >
                        <img id="closeFrame1" name="closeFrame1" style="position:absolute;top:207.5px;
                            left:312.5px;border:0; z-index:10000011"
                            title="Close" alt="Close" width="12px" height="12px"
                            src="http://www.playerhd2.pw/jwplayer5/x-fonter.gif" />
                    </a>
                                                <div id="second_ads_tmp" class="ad" align="center"
                                style="border: 0px red solid; top:195px; left:287.5px;
                                       z-index:50000012; opacity: 0.0">
                                <IFRAME style="z-index: 1000;" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=250 
                            SRC='http://vm.timeinabottle.pw/XnewadsX/ads1x300go.html'></IFRAME>
                            <!-- END TAG -->                            </div>
                                    </div>
                <div id="total_banner" onkeydown="return false" style="display: none;" >
                    <div class="container_embed"></div>
                    <div align="center" id="ads_banner1"
                        style="border: 0px blue solid; position: absolute;
                               top:445px; left:0px; width: 100%; height: 90px;
                               z-index:10000010; opacity:0.9">
                                            </div>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:hideOverlayBanner('total_banner', 'ads_banner1')" 
                        style="display: none;" >
                        <img id="closeFrame_banner" name="closeFrame_banner" style="position:absolute;top:450px;
                            left: 90px ;border:0; z-index:10000011"
                            title="Close" alt="Close" width="12px" height="12px"
                            src="http://www.playerhd2.pw/jwplayer5/x-fonter.gif" />
                    </a>
                                                <div id="second_banner_ads_tmp" align="center" id="ads_banner1_second"
                                style="display: ; border: 0px red solid; position: absolute;
                                       top:445px; left:0px; width: 100%; height: 90px;
                                       z-index:50000012; opacity:0.0">
                                <IFRAME id="secondFrame" style="z-index: 1000; "
                                FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=728 HEIGHT=90
                                SRC="">
                            </IFRAME>                            </div>
                                    </div>
```

This is the iframe code on my web page:

```
<iframe src="http://www.playerhd2.pw/channel.php?file=130&width=890&height=640&autostart=true"
        width="890"
        height="640"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        allowfullscreen
        sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

Comment: `sandbox` will apply to **ALL** content within the iframe

Comment: @zer00ne can i disable all the <div id= elements with sandbox ?

Comment: A div is a passive element...structure...so when you want it disabled do you mean not visible or totally gone?

Comment: @zer00ne I want that not be visible div elements

Comment: @zer00ne How is it possible ??!!

Comment: I'm at work atm, but I'll be happy to answer your question later on.

Comment: okay @zer00ne then I will be waiting for your answer :)

Comment: Do you own www.playerhd2.pw? If not, this would be impossible. But if you do own www.playerhd2.pw, it's possible and I can show you, just tell me your objective. I believe your objective is to somehow neutralize the ad...

Comment: @zer00ne No I'm not owner of www.playerhd2.pw ! , I want to use this iframe on my web page but i want to disable div elements of this link by sandbox.

Comment: The sandbox doesn't have that fine grain control. Ran a copy of the page in secure environment and it triggers 9 different security warnings upon initial page load (which failed to load anything further of course.) I advise another way of playing content,

Comment: @zer00ne What's your advise for another way ?

Comment: Is the video you want on your site or on a 3rd party site? The best course of action is to host the video on your own site or YouTube.

Comment: @zer00ne I want to put this Channel on my site , This channel is for 3rd party site.

Comment: @zer00ne I'm waiting for your response

Comment: Is the video content static? Is it updated regularly? Is there a reason why you can't download the video them upload it to your own site? Is the content licensed? Any option involving less with this 3rd party site the better. The way this 3rd party site pushes ads is aggressive like adware/malware. Doesn't your computer's fans rev up to maximum spin when the video is playing?

Comment: @zer00ne It is Live Stream and its not video , for this reason its not possible to upload it to my own site. Then just I can use Iframe of this Live Stream on my site. but I want to disable the div elements till i can remove ads like adware/malware on my site.

Comment: @zer00ne How can i stop div elements on Iframe ?

Comment: You can't unless you own the site from whence they originated from.